# Invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I am trying to do some time series analysis on a dataset I have but running into this error message when trying to plot a graph to test for stationarity

> ValueError: view limit minimum -36816.450000000004 is less than 1 and
>   is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a
>   non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

This despite the fact that my Date column is in datetime format.

This is the code I have

```
rolmean = tester_d.set_index('Date').rolling(window=365).mean()
rolstd =  tester_d.set_index('Date').rolling(window=365).std()
#plotting rolling stats
orig = plt.plot(tester_d,color='blue',label='Original')
mean = plt.plot(rolmean,color='red',label='Rolling Mean')
std = plt.plot(rolstd,color='black',label='Rolling Std')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard Deviation')
plt.show(block=False)
```

Here is a sample of my data

```
    Date    value
0   2016-01-01  569410.40
1   2016-01-02  1160518.41
2   2016-01-03  823535.26
3   2016-01-04  894024.59
4   2016-01-05  911309.93
5   2016-01-06  949347.34
6   2016-01-07  1175089.57
7   2016-01-08  6134562.65
8   2016-01-09  1000653.51
9   2016-01-10  601852.78
10  2016-01-11  713232.13
11  2016-01-12  887282.26
12  2016-01-13  793328.93
13  2016-01-14  1328415.43
14  2016-01-15  1027134.81
```

These are the values I get for rolmean and rolstd:

```
          value 
Date    
2016-01-01  NaN
2016-01-02  NaN
2016-01-03  NaN
2016-01-04  NaN
2016-01-05  NaN
2016-01-06  NaN
2016-01-07  NaN
2016-01-08  NaN
2016-01-09  NaN
2016-01-10  NaN
2016-01-11  NaN
2016-01-12  NaN
2016-01-13  NaN
2016-01-14  NaN
2016-01-15  NaN
```

Comment: What is the datatypes of `rolmean` & `rolstd ` after you perform the calculation?

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf just added that now